# How can you unitalize a higher category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, higher-category-theory

Given an associative nonunital algebra $A$, there are (at least) two standard ways to produce a unital algebra $A'$ together with a map $A \to A'$. Following the discussion in the comments below, these are:

- The *(free) unitalization* of $A$ is the unital algebra achieved by simply adding to $A$ a new element which you declare to be the unit.
- The *multiplier algebra* of $A$ is the algebra of all $A$-linear endomorphism of $A$-as-a-right-$A$-module.

In C*-land, nonunital algebras are thought of noncompact spaces, free unitalization corresponds to the one-point compactification, and the multiplier algebra to the Stone-Cech compactification. I remark that if $A$ already has a unit, then passing to the multiplier algebra doesn't change $A$, whereas free unitalization does.

There is a similar construction in categories. Suppose $C$ is a non-unital category (meaning it has an associative composition, but not necessarily identities morphisms). The *free unitalization* of $C$ is produced by adding to $C$ a new morphism for each object in $C$, declaring that morphism to be the identity on that object. The *multiplier category* of $C$ is given by studying natural transformation as between the representable functors $\hom_C(-,c)$ for $c$ ranging over the objectin $C$s, and to declare that $C'$ is the category with objects $\mathrm{ob}(C)$ and morphisms $\hom_{C'}(c,c') = \text{natural transformations}(\hom_{C}(-,c), \hom_C(-,c'))$.

**Main question:** Have these unitalizations, and in particular the multiplier category, been studied for $\infty$-categories?

For example, I find myself in the following situation. I have a semisimplicial (no degeneracies) space satisfying the Segal condition. I think of it as a "nonunital $(\infty,1)$-category". The free unitalization is just the output of freely creating degeneracy maps, thereby producing a complete Segal space. For my application, I want the multiplier category (as Segal space, complete or not I can handle).

Comment: The first construction goes by the name "Dorroh extension by $\mathbb{Z}$."  [In ring theory this is actually a very nice, natural, and interesting construction.  So in the future, you might be careful about using judgemental words.]  The second construction [which is also nice, natural, and interesting] does not embed $A$ in a unital ring in general.   Consider the case where $A=\{0,x\}$ has trivial multiplication and $x+x=0$.

Comment: The same problem Pace points out already comes up for embedding semigroups in monoids (so the one-object case).  If the semigroup does not act faithfully on the right of itself, then taking the endomorphisms of the right regular representation do not give an embedding.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I agree the one I find more interesting is not always an embedding, although there is always a map. I don't apologize for this choice of valuative word --- of course it is intended to (slightly) provoke, but mostly I think that by clearly broadcasting my own biases, I can get answers that are more useful for my application. In my case, I have some objects which have identities and some which (as far as I can tell) do not, and it is important that I unitalize without destroying the identities I already have.

Comment: BTW the "interesting Unitilization" can produce uninteresting results. Let X be your favorite set and define a product by xy=x. Then this gives a semigroup whose Unitilization is trivial.

Comment: You might be interested in the conceptual framework proposed in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3524v1) paper, although there are no higher categories in it. Read in particular S7.3

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked for, but maybe you will find https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0212 relevant.

Comment: Concerning the pre-question, I suggest the names "unitalization" and "multiplier algebra".

Comment: @HeinrichD These are good names, thanks! I have updated the question.

Comment: @PaceNielsen With Heinrich's comments, I have removed the language you found disparaging. (I didn't intend "entire" disparagement, and do apologize.) I do want to clarify the difference between procedures and their outputs. I make no claim about whether the outputs of these unitalizations are interesting or not for a given input. Simply that (free) unitalization, qua procedure, is more straightforward and regular-behaving than construction of the multiplier algebra. For instance, free unitalization is a left adjoint to a forgetful functor, and pretty much everything I think one can say about

Comment: it in general comes from abstract nonsense of adjunctions. I certainly enjoy abstract nonsense, but any individual left adjoint isn't too rich. On the other hand, construction of the multiplier algebra is not a functor, and yet nevertheless it is "natural". This I find very rich.

Comment: There also is the bimultiplication algebra $M_A$ (see e. g. [Extensions and obstructions for rings](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255454537) by Mac Lane). In a sense it is "even more interesting" than the multiplier algebra: it gives a crossed bimodule$$0\to Z_A\to A\to M_A\to P_A\to0$$which seems to be the proper analog of$$0\to Z(G)\to G\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to\operatorname{Out}(G)\to0.$$Might be more useful as the kernel is smaller than with the one-sided multipliers.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Very cool. I did not know that construcion.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz That paper is very interesting. I have begun reading it. In the example I care about, it is possible (I go back and forth about how likely it is) that every object has an identity morphism, at least in some naive sense. So I think your paper might in fact be just what I need for the actual project...

Comment: It would correspond to declaring $f\in\hom_{C'}(x,y)$ to be a pair$$\left\langle f\cdot:\hom_C(\_,x)\to\hom_C(\_,y),\cdot f:\hom_C(y,\_)\to\hom_C(x,\_)\right\rangle$$such that$$(\alpha\cdot f)\circ\beta=\alpha\circ(f\cdot\beta)$$for any $\alpha\in\hom_C(y,y')$, $\beta\in\hom_C(x',x)$.